# PHP,JSON write to table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a problem creating dynamic tables for my project. With AJAX, I get data from PHP and JSON converts the array into a table but the dump doesn't work.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    if ($row["Author"] !== "" && $row["Name"])
    {
      $table_data = array(
        "Author" => "".$row["Author"]."",
        "Name" => "".$row["Name"]."",
        "Text" => "".$row["Text"].""
      );
      array_push($filtr, json_encode($table_data));

      echo "".json_encode($table_data).""; 
    }
  }
}
```

```js
$.post("../include/filtr_callback.php", { sel_id: "" + knih_callback + "" }, function(data, status) {
  //var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
  var mydata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
  mydata = "[ " + mydata + " ];"
  console.log(mydata);

  var tbl = $("<table/>").attr("id", "table-data");
  $("#tabulka").append(tbl);
  for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    var td1 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Author"] + "</td>";
    var td2 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Name"] + "</td>";
    var td3 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Name"] + "</td>";
    var td4 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Text"] + "</td></tr>";
    $("#table-data").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you are echoing a json encoded array every iteration of the loop.  That is going to return invalid json to the front end.  You need to collect all your results into a single element, and echo that whole object json_encoded at the end,  And don't append "" to it, as that is unnecessary

Comment: Did you tried my solution below?

Comment: Yes,Not work. Data in <table> write "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the result after you finish iteration of the loop. So I have created a secondary `array` called `$table` where I store results after each iteration.

```
$table = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row["Author"] !== "" && $row["Name"]){
            $table_data = array(
                "Author" => "".$row["Author"]."",
                "Name" => "".$row["Name"]."",
                "Text" => "".$row["Text"].""
            );
            array_push($filtr,json_encode($table_data));
            $table[] = $table_data;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($table); 
}
```

I have also made some small changes in your javascript code. You don't need to call anymore `JSON.stringify` on your response and also `mydata` is array itself after `JSON.parse` so I also removed `mydata = "[ " + mydata + " ];"`.

```
$.post("../include/filtr_callback.php", { sel_id: "" + knih_callback + "" }, function(data, status) {
  var mydata = JSON.parse(data); 
  console.log(mydata);

  var tbl = $("<table/>").attr("id", "table-data");
  $("#tabulka").append(tbl);
  for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    var td1 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Author"] + "</td>";
    var td2 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Name"] + "</td>";
    var td3 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Name"] + "</td>";
    var td4 = "<td>" + mydata[i]["Text"] + "</td></tr>";
    $("#table-data").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4); 
  }
});
```

Comment: `mydata = "[ " + mydata + " ];"` needs to be removed as well